# Links suddenly stop reacting after migrating MyFaces 1.2 to 2.1

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I recently switched my Eclipse Indigo project from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.1 (using MyFaces). Using Tomcat 7.

Strange thing happens: I set up a project, and it works fine for some short
time, and then suddenly (maybe after I do "clean") stops working in a sense that
clicking a command link does not produce any action, backing bean's method is not
called, just nothing happens. I have tried to do project "clean" and Eclipse
restart, and even system restart but it did not help. Only thing that helped is
that I created a brand new workspace, and new project - but same thing happened:
this too worked only for short time and suddenly stoped working in the same way
- command links are just not reacting to clicks, and there is no way I can debug Java
code to at least localize the problem.

What could be the reason for such a strange behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update:** this is the JavaScript error reported:

```
myfaces is not defined
onclick()onclick (line 2)
event = click clientX=840, clientY=252

return myfaces.oam.submitForm("j_id_6", "j_id_6:LOGIN");

function onclick(event) {
return myfaces.oam.submitForm("j_id_6", "j_id_6:LOGIN");
}
```

Here is the original XHTML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Login</title>    
</h:head>
<body style="background-color:#3d3d3d;" text="#000000" link="#cc0000" alink="#666666" vlink="#cc0000" onload="document.forms[0].USERNAME.focus();">
<f:view>

<h:form target="_top">

    <table border="0" align="center" width="810" style="border: 2px black solid; background-image:url(images/header.jpg); margin:auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <table align="center" width="810" style="border: 2px black solid; background-color:#ffffff;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" height="10" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle">

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
            <table width="778" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="778"><h1>Login</h1>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                              <tr>                                  
                                <td height="20"><font class="text">User Name: </font></td>
                                <td height="20"><font class="text"><t:inputText forceId="true" id="USERNAME" maxlength="50" value="#{LoginBean.username}" size="26" /></font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="20"><font class="text">Password: </font></td>
                                <td height="20"><font class="text"><h:inputSecret maxlength="30" value="#{LoginBean.password}" size="26" /></font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="20" colspan="2" align="right"><h:commandLink id="LOGIN" action="#{LoginBean.doLogin}"><h:graphicImage style="border: none" value="images/login.png" /></h:commandLink></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</h:form>    

</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Login</title></head>
<body style="background-color:#3d3d3d;" text="#000000" link="#cc0000" alink="#666666" vlink="#cc0000" onload="document.forms[0].USERNAME.focus();"><form id="j_id2030916047_790d5181" name="j_id2030916047_790d5181" method="post" action="/EWC/login.faces" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="_top">

    <table border="0" align="center" width="810" style="border: 2px black solid; background-image:url(images/header.jpg); margin:auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </table>

    <table align="center" width="810" style="border: 2px black solid; background-color:#ffffff;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" height="10" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle">

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
            <table width="778" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>

                    <td valign="top" width="778"><h1>Login</h1>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>                                    
                                <td height="20"><font class="text">User Name: </font></td>
                                <td height="20"><font class="text"><input id="USERNAME" name="USERNAME" type="text" value="" maxlength="50" size="26" /></font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="20"><font class="text">Password: </font></td>

                                <td height="20"><font class="text"><input type="password" name="j_id2030916047_790d5181:j_id2030916047_790d51ba" maxlength="30" size="26" /></font></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="20" colspan="2" align="right"><script type="text/javascript" src="/EWC/javax.faces.resource/oamSubmit.js.faces?ln=org.apache.myfaces"></script><a href="#" onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('j_id2030916047_790d5181','j_id2030916047_790d5181:LOGIN');" id="j_id2030916047_790d5181:LOGIN"><img src="images/login.png" style="border: none" /></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table><input type="hidden" name="j_id2030916047_790d5181_SUBMIT" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="5s3ZqoVcUIwarcQb6pVzFIPhMJIzbVHnjMrXdtgA1Nten7grU/y0hMGbHtFvIExuKQOwB3IGzcSDeuPfijYMcnK23q/2N1mduMdr6RskySGELSaI2w93nL9b8NE=" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't you have any logs?

Comment: Which log would you like? I'll try to provide.

Comment: don't you see any log in the console window in eclipse or in the tomcat log? what is your bean request scope (session, view, ...) . maybe you could post some code?

Comment: Based on the information so far I can only make guesses. Let me do a first guess: all those buttons perform ajax requests and the ajax responses have all returned a `ViewExpiredException` because the sessions are not persisted on server clean/hotdeploy cycle. Use the HTTP traffic debugger tool in your webbrowser (press F12 in Chrome/IE9 or use Firebug in Firefox) to investigate and confirm this. Then we can talk further.

Comment: @roel @BalusC Nothing is in log files, no errors reported - that's the problem, I don't know where to start. All beans are `request` scoped. Ajax is NOT used. Using Firefox, will try Firebug.

Comment: Were you migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.1 or was you only changing the project facet from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.1 and thus the application was already designed with JSF 2.1 in mind?

Comment: @BalusC I migrated from 1.x to 2.x. Had to change all files from jsp to xhtml, changed file headers, etc, fixed quite a few things, and it finaly worked. However, it stoped working for no reason. As I said, I then did a new clean workspace and project in Eclipse, and the whole thing just repeated - firts it worked and then stoped.

Comment: Okay, with a new project do you mean that you just created a brand new  dynamic web project with a simple test Facelets page and test backing bean without reusing any artifact from the original code?

Comment: @BalusC No. I created brand new dynamic web project, and added all files that I modified previously, the files that used to belong to original project. When I think twice, I think I also did a simple "hello worls" project before I started the upgrade, and it worked.

Comment: I installed Firebug, but don't know what to look for? It's just a login page that I have, but it doesn't fire events, it never calls my backing bean.

Comment: Press F12 to open Firebug. Go to *Net* tab. You see a live tracking of all HTTP requests in there. Verify if the HTTP request is actually been sent or not when you press the button. Verify what kind of response it returned.

Comment: @BalusC Seems like no HTTP request is sent at all. :-(

Comment: And this is using the standard `<h:form><h:commandButton>` components? Well, seems a browser or JavaScript specific issue. You'd need to trim down a copy of the problematic page into the smallest possible and self-containing code (remove as much as unrelated/irrelevant tags/attributes as long as you can still reproduce the problem) and then include it in your question. This way we can eventually point out the problem in the markup for you.

Comment: Same thing happens in IE. Will add some more info to the question.

Comment: @BalusC Ok, finaly an error in Firebug console when I click the button: "myfaces is not defined. onclick()". I have pasted generated HTML above in the question, please have a look. There is a strange looking html-comment.

Comment: So you are using command links, not command buttons. That would have indicated a possible JavaScript issue much sooner... Do you have replaced the `<head>` throughout your templates by `<h:head>`?

Comment: No, I am using `<head>`.

Comment: When I click in Firebug on that error, it tells me `No Javascript on this page.

If <script> tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct).`

Comment: Are you able to open `http://localhost:8080/EWC/javax.faces.resource/oamSubmit.js.faces?ln=org.apache.myfaces` ?

Comment: No, not able to open that page.

Comment: I think the problem is my initial Faces servlet, I am overriding `org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet`. When I don't override, it works ok. 
`
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>`

Comment: This is what happens: My first page is /login.faces. When I open this page, the class that owerrides `MyFacesServlet` is called TWICE. First time login.faces is the caller, and next time the caller is `/javax.faces.resource/oamSubmit.js.faces`. This second time I execute `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect( "/login.faces" )`. When I comment out this sendRedirect line all works well. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>    
    <param-value>true</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

add it in ur Web.xml 
everything will start.